# How to show multiple records in columns with repeater?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am in the middle of a project. I have a table for tab menu in sql server database that I have attached it's image.
my tab menu has a style like bellow :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Name1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Name2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Name3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Name4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <br /><br />
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">

            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="imageslist/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" /> ...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
<div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
</div>      
</div>
```

I want to connect this tab menu to database with repeater or any usefull control. How can I do this?

[image: MenuTabledb]

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

           <div class="col-sm-4">
    <ul class="nav navbar-link navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" /><%# Eval("FName") %></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imageslist/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" /><%# Eval("ParentID").ToString() %></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list/tik.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;" /><%# Eval("Active").ToString() %></a></li>            
    </ul>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```